# How to plot predicted data of a GLMM from the package glmmTMB?

Tags: r, plot, regression, mixed-models, glmmtmb

i have the following data and created a model with the package glmmTMB in R for plant diameters ~ plant density (number of plants) with a random plot effect:

```
d <- data.frame (diameter = c(17,16,15,13,11, 19,17,15,11,11, 19,15,14,11,8),
                      plant_density = c(1000,2000,3000,4000,5000, 1000,2000,3000,4000,5000, 1000,2000,3000,4000,5000),
                      plot = c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3))

glmm.model <- glmmTMB(diameter ~  plant_density + (1|plot),
                        data = d,
                        na.action = na.omit,
                        family="gaussian",
                        ziformula = ~ 0)
```

My intention was to create a plot with predicted diameter data for different plant densities with an included random plot effect. So i tried to predict the data:

```
new.dat <- data.frame(diameter= d$diameter,
                      plant_density = d$plant_density,
                      plot= d$plot) 

new.dat$prediction <- predict(glmm.model, new.data = new.dat, 
                              type = "response", re.form = NA)
```

Unfortunately I get an output for every plot but wanted a generalized prediction for the diameter ~ plant density.

My goal is to create a plot like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wwnN.png), but with a regression model from glmmTMB which consider the random effect.

Thanks for ur help!

Comment: when you say "consider the random effect"- do you mean you want different curves for different levels of d$plot ?

Comment: Hi! No, I wanted to create new data according to the measured ones (f.e. for 1 to 8000 plants) so I can plot one line to show the general context. The plots just are three areas (sampling method) where I measured my data.

Comment: is this what your looking for: plot(ggeffects::ggpredict(glmm.model))

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Thats what I'm looking for. I think the random effects are considered :-)

Comment: One last question: Can you tell me how to change the limits of the x axis from 0 to 20? I don't know how to include it in the code?

Comment: do you mean the y-axis? there's nothing in that range for your x-axis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240797/discussion-between-schneiderhansl-and-sushichef).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ggeffects` package makes this type of thing very easy to implement and customize.

For example

```
library('ggplot2')
library('glmmTMB')
library('ggeffects')
d <- data.frame (diameter = c(17,16,15,13,11, 19,17,15,11,11, 19,15,14,11,8),
                 plant_density = c(1000,2000,3000,4000,5000, 1000,2000,3000,4000,5000, 1000,2000,3000,4000,5000),
                 plotx = as.factor( c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3)))

glmm.model <- glmmTMB(diameter ~  plant_density + (1|plotx),
                      data = d,
                      family="gaussian")

# basically what your looking for
plot(ggpredict(glmm.model, terms = "plant_density"))

# with additional a change of limits on the y-axis
plot(ggpredict(glmm.model, terms = "plant_density")) + 
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 20))
```

You can really do whatever you'd like with it from there, changing colors, themes, scales, [the package has some nice vignettes as well](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for ur help!! At least I wanted to predict values from the model. I measured densities from 1000 to 5000 which helped me to create a model. Now I wanted to predict new plant diameters for density values between 0 and 10000. I tried to change the x axis but R shows only the regression for the given densities.
Is there any way to solve this problem with that package?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, if your asking for a prediction interval for new levels: I don't think its quite as straight forward, but is easy enough even with predict(new_dat, type = interval), it might be answered somewhere else on SO or you can ask another question